# jQuery group fire elements that are members of a parent modal element

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a group of selectors I want to use hide() on and I have selectors that are named the same elsewhere in the UI (in other modals). What is the most efficient way to hide all elements related to the parent modal?

Like this or is this even possible and what is this type of syntax called I have seen it somewhere before?

```
$some_parent_element = $("#id");

$(".class1, .class2, .class3", $some_parent_element).hide();
```

or like this?

```
$($some_parent_element + " .class1", $some_parent_element + " .class2", $some_parent_element + " .class3").hide();
```

the second seems lengthy code wise.  Or is there an even better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand exactly what you're after, but it sounds like you want [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
var $someObj = $('#id');
...
$('.class1, .class2, .class3').add($someObj).hide();
```

If you want to search for nodes *under* `$someObj` you'd simply use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
var $someObj = $('#id'),
    $descendants = $someObj.find('.class1, .class2, .class3');
```

Comment: Sure, that is actually a good way to go about it using find. I wanted to see if this was called some type of syntax like referencing and if jQuery automatically FOUND nodes using the first way?  Like $(".class", $obj).hide(); Or maybe thats not possible in jQuery?

Comment: Ahhh, that is exactly what I was referring to I just didn't know what it was called.  Andre thanks!